# Price book entry is in a different pricebook than the one assigned to the opportunity Error

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-setup

I'm facing the issue while deploying the test class in production.

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: PricebookEntryId (pricebook entry is in a different pricebook than the one assigned to the opportunity): [PricebookEntryId]

```java
//Création de Product
Product2 prod = new Product2(Name = 'Product Test', IsActive = true);
insert prod;
        
//Création PriceBook & PriceBookEntry
Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
//Pricebook2 pb = new Pricebook2( Id = pricebookId, IsActive = true);
//update pb;
        
PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(unitprice = 0.01, Product2Id = prod.Id, Pricebook2Id = pricebookId, IsActive = true); 
insert pbe;
        
//Création d'opp
        
List<Opportunity> testOpps = new List<Opportunity>();
Date myDate = Date.newInstance(2023, 4, 8);
for(Integer i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    testOpps.add(new Opportunity(Name = 'TestOpp'+i, StageName = 'Négociation', closeDate = myDate, Pricebook2Id = pricebookId));
    //opportIds.add(testOpps[i].Id);
}
insert testOpps;
        
//Création d'Opportunity Line Items
List<OpportunityLineItem> testOppsLineItems = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
for(Integer i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    testOppsLineItems.add(new OpportunityLineItem(OpportunityId = testOpps[i].Id, Quantity = 6, TotalPrice = 27, PricebookEntryId = pbe.Id));
    //opportIds.add(testOpps[i].Id);
}
insert testOppsLineItems;
```

Comment: Does uncommenting the `Pricebook2 pb = new Pricebook2(...)` and `update pb;` lines resolve the error? I know that needs to be done for custom pricebooks (to be able to query/use them in tests) but I'm not sure if it's required for the standard pricebook.

Comment: No, it does not unfortuntley

Comment: are there triggers or flows or PB or WFR on OpportunityLineItem or Opportunity that are altering the value of `Opportunity.Pricebook2Id` or `OpportunityLineItem.PricebookEntryId`? You definitely don't need to update the standard pricebook